# Updating an iOS app with only the Bundle ID

Tags: ios, mobile

I have an iOS app which I have developed and packaged and I was ready to submit to the app store. However the client has requested that I update an existing app which was developed by another unrelated developer rather then submit a new one. Basically using my new code.
All I have been provided with so far is a Bundle ID. Obviously if I try and add a new App ID under my developer account I get an error:
"The bundle identifier you have specified is already in use. Please select another."
Is there any way around this? I can't see any easy way as this Bundle will never be under my provisioning profile.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You might need that other developers itunes account to publish your project :(

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. You need to use their iTunes Connect Credentials and upload your App
2. They need to add you as team member (Add your Apple Id to their account as their team member)
   For this they need to invite you to join to their program and you need to accept their invitation.

They can invite you by logging to their developer account and :

```
Developer Account->Member Center->People->Invite a person to your team
```

Refer:

[Account Management](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html)